# Set Carbon Timezone only once

Tags: laravel, timezone, php-carbon

i have a laravel project where is use only `Europe/Rome` timezone, and so i was wondering if there was a way to tell Carbon to use that timezone as default.

So far i've founded this:

```
date_default_timezone_set($config->get('app.timezone', 'UTC'));
```

But i would like to know if there was a cleaner way to do it

Comment: You could set it in your `php.ini`, I suppose.

Comment: I dint exactly get your issue as in why would you set time zone like that it makes sense only while displaying

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set your timezone for the whole application by configuring `app.php` file in `config` folder.

See more:

https://github.com/laravel/laravel/blob/master/config/app.php#L70

Comment: and carbon will use that timezone?

Comment: Yes it will use that timezone wherever you use carbon.